# Site-To-Site IPSec between StrongSwan and Zyxel NSG200

Tags: vpn, ipsec, site-to-site-vpn, strongswan, zyxel

I'm trying to initiate an IPSec connection (Site-to-Site) between a Debian 10 server with StrongSwan and a Nebula NSG200.

Let's assume:

- Debian server:

  - Public IP : 50.50.50.45
  - Private Network: 10.1.0.0/16
- Nebula NSG200:

  - Public IP : 100.100.100.123
  - Private Network : 10.40.0.0/24

But the authentication fail every time. I got the folowing messages in debian's logs.

I can't understand why the authentiaction failed !

```
...
charon: 13[NET] received packet: from 100.100.100.123[500] to 50.50.50.45[500] (480 bytes)
charon: 13[ENC] parsed IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) V V V ]
charon: 13[ENC] received unknown vendor ID: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:...
charon: 13[ENC] received unknown vendor ID: yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:...
charon: 13[ENC] received unknown vendor ID: zz:zz:zz:zz:zz:...
charon: 13[IKE] 100.100.100.123 is initiating an IKE_SA
charon: 13[CFG] selected proposal: IKE:AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_512_256/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_512/MODP_1024
charon: 13[IKE] remote host is behind NAT
charon: 13[ENC] generating IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(MULT_AUTH) ]
charon: 13[NET] sending packet: from 50.50.50.45[500] to 100.100.100.123[500] (312 bytes)
charon: 14[NET] received packet: from 100.100.100.123[4500] to 50.50.50.45[4500] (320 bytes)
charon: 14[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH request 1 [ IDi CERTREQ AUTH SA TSi TSr N(HTTP_CERT_LOOK) N(INIT_CONTACT) N(ESP_TFC_PAD_N) N(NON_FIRST_FRAG) ]
charon: 14[IKE] received 1 cert requests for an unknown ca
charon: 14[CFG] looking for peer configs matching 50.50.50.45[%any]...100.100.100.123[10.0.1.250]
charon: 14[CFG] no matching peer config found
charon: 14[IKE] received ESP_TFC_PADDING_NOT_SUPPORTED, not using ESPv3 TFC padding
charon: 14[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ N(AUTH_FAILED) ]
charon: 14[NET] sending packet: from 50.50.50.45[4500] to 100.100.100.123[4500] (96 bytes)
...
```

#### StrongSwan side

`/etc/ipsec.conf` :

```
config setup
        charondebug="all"
        uniqueids=yes
conn deb-to-neb
        type=tunnel
        auto=start
        keyexchange=ikev2
        authby=secret
        left=100.100.100.123
        leftsubnet=10.40.0.1/24
        right=50.50.50.45
        rightsubnet=10.1.0.1/16
        ike=aes256-sha512-modp1024!
        esp=aes256-sha512!
        aggressive=yes
        keyingtries=%forever
        ikelifetime=86400s
        lifetime=3600s
        dpdaction=restart
```

`/etc/ipsec.secrets` :

```
100.100.100.123 50.50.50.45 : PSK "MySuperSecret"
50.50.50.45 100.100.100.123 : PSK "MySuperSecret"
```

#### Nebula side

[Screen Nebula Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISL0z.png)

- Phase 1

  - IKE version : IKEv2
  - Encryption : AES256
  - Authentication : SHA512
  - Diffie-Hellman Group : DH2
  - Lifetime (seconds) : 86400
- Phase 2 (Set 1)

  - Encryption : AES256
  - Authentication : SHA512
  - PFS Group : DH2
  - Lifetime (seconds) : 3600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an authentication error, the problem is that your configuration doesn't match:

```
charon: 14[CFG] looking for peer configs matching 50.50.50.45[%any]...100.100.100.123[10.0.1.250]
charon: 14[CFG] no matching peer config found
```

In particular, the remote identity. Because you haven't configured *rightid*, it defaults to the remote IP address (`100.100.100.123`), but that does not match the identity the peer sends (`10.0.1.250`). Since changing the identity on the peer does not seem to be an option (based on that screenshot), try configuring `rightid=10.0.1.250`.

Comment: This work like a charm thank's a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work, but for some reason i cannot ping my Zyxel LAN from where my StrongSwan is hosted. I am able to ping and access network resources through my Zyxel LAN network to my StrongSwan VPN client/network as well as ping. Am I missing something?
Please advise.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/509197)